# SharePoint 2013 and AutoCAD

Tags: 2013, third-party-software

Environment: 2010 Enterprise, but have 2013 ready to be deployed

I'm looking at various solutions for browser-based CAD file viewing and markup (or a comparable alternative). We currently run SP2010, but I have 2013 ready to go as soon as I'm comfortable upgrading. What I want to know is if anyone knows of 2013 features that may aid in my quest for CAD-browser integration?

For example, I've seen vague references from Autodesk that some of their software integrates in to SP2013 but I don't know anyone who has actually used that feature, and I can't find much data about exactly WHAT it is and HOW it works (all I know is it involves Vault 2013). Autodesk's marketing materials about it are just that - marketing. Lots of buzz words about "collaboration and efficiency" and no actual explanation of what the heck they're talking about.

Does anyone have experience with 2013 apps or other software that integrates CAD drawings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done some work with the AutoDesk product called Navisworks.  With 2010's blob caching that allows range requests, I was able to implement their activex control and emulate how SP does the office webapps (view in browser) but with navisworks files.  So this would be possible with 2013 as well assuming you have some way to view the file in the browser (like an activex control).

I'm also real interested in testing out skydrive pro (available with office 2013 pro) to sync documents locally on someone's computer.  They have changed how they do this between SP Workspace 2010 and skydrive pro so it now actually works with cad based software which often times require external references.  Also during my testing skydrive pro works with SP 2010 in addition to SP 2013.

I am not familiar with what Autodesk has done to better integrate with SP 2013.  I'll believe it when I see it. :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the suggestions. X-refs are the biggest pain with doing this so if skydrive can help handle them now it may be an even better way to do it. I'll start testing it and post the results.

Comment: So I've finally managed to get back on this project and have tested a few different ways of doing it. The first method that works is a combination of AutoCAD's built-in FTP functionality and the AvePoint File Share Navigator (pointed at the FTP file share). This works by publishing the files to the SP site with the File Share Navigator, and having a drive mapped to the file share itself. It's messy, but it works. SkyDrive, it turns out, seems to be the better answer. You still have to map a drive to the library for AutoCAD to be able to save to it, but after that it works like a charm (so far)